# A 2-variables limit involving inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: limits

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)} \left(\frac{\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac1y-\tan^{-1}3}{(x-1)(y-2)}\right)\sin^{-1}(y-2)$

I'm stuck at $\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,2)} \frac{2-y}{x-1}$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as $\displaystyle \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{2-(k+2)}{h+1-1}=\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{-k}{h}$. Now if we approach the origin through the line $y=x$ then we get the limit as $\displaystyle\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{-h}{h}=-1$.
But if we approach the origin through the line $y=-x$ then we get the limit as $\displaystyle\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{h}{h}=1$.
Hence by approcahing the same point through two different routes we get different limit. Hence it does not exist.
(Note that for the real line limits we can only approach a point from the left or right, but for 2D and higher dimensions...we can approach a particular point through infinite directions and infinite curves. **IF limit  exists, all such direction should give the same limit**).
However if we had iterated limit instead of double limit then the limit
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\lim_{y\to 2} \frac{2-y}{x-1}$ is just $0$ whereas the other iterated limit(taking limit wrt x first) does not exist.

However I do not understand how it relates to your original question of the limit with tan inverses. There you you should end up with
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)} \left(\frac{\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac1y-\tan^{-1}3}{(x-1)}\right)\frac{\sin^{-1}(y-2)}{(y-2)}$$. Here the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}\frac{\sin^{-1}(y-2)}{(y-2)}$ should give you $1$ directly ( You can again use the substitution $y=k+2$ and $x=h+1$ and then expand the maclaurin series for $\sin^{-1}(k)$ and then divide by $k$ and take the limit to get it as $1$ as $k\to 0$)
But the expression $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)} \left(\frac{\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac1y-\tan^{-1}3}{(x-1)}\right)$ is just $\frac{-2\tan^{-1}(3)}{(x-1)}$ which is of the form $\frac{\text{finite}}{0}$ gives you a non-existing limit directly without the use of the "paths and routes" argument that I used.